# How to access a fragment's view from an async class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, pdf-viewer

I have an activity that consists of a tablayout of 3 tabs. Each tab is a fragment and all of them contains a pdf view to view different pdf files.

I have written a class for Pdf Viewer. I need to call that class in numerous fragments to open pdf file in that fragment. But I'm not being able to pass the context properly and access that fragmet's PDFview. I'm using C.pdfviewer.PDFView as my PDFviewer.

Here is my code:

MyFragment.class

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

PDFView pdfView;
String url = "mysite.pdf";
public MyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfragment, container, false);
    pdfView = (PDFView)view.findViewById(R.id.pdfViewer);

    new RetrievePDFStream(this).execute(url);

   return view;
}
}
```

RetrievePDFStream.class

```
public class RetrievePDFStream extends AsyncTask<String, Void, byte[]> {

public Fragment fContext;
PDFView pdfView;

public RetrievePDFStream(Fragment fContext) {
    this.fContext = fContext;
}

@Override
protected byte[] doInBackground(String... strings) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(byte[] inputStream) {
    View view = fContext.getView();
    pdfView = (PDFView)view.findViewById(R.id.pdfViewer);
    pdfView.fromBytes(inputStream).load();
}
}
```

MyFragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="app.nvest.helpinsure.Fragment.MyFragment"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000">

<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pdfViewer"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below code;

```
new RetrievePDFStream(getActivity()).execute(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `Activities`, `fragment` has different life cycle. in your code

> Replace this:

```
new RetrievePDFStream(this).execute(url); //this
```

> With

```
new RetrievePDFStream(getActivity().execute(url))
```

You can use getActivity(), which returns the activity associated with a fragment.

Comment: try getActivity().getBaseContext().execute(url). if still not helps, post your logs

Answer (score 0):

You can Achieve this by using callback mechanism. Use below code.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements ApiResponseCallback {

PDFView pdfView;
String url = "mysite.pdf";
public MyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfragment, container, false);
    pdfView = (PDFView)view.findViewById(R.id.pdfViewer);

    new RetrievePDFStream(this).execute(url);

   return view;
}
public void onByteArrayRecievedFromAPI(byte[] inputStream){
    pdfView = (PDFView)getView.findViewById(R.id.pdfViewer);
    pdfView.fromBytes(inputStream).load();

}
public interface ApiResponseCallback{
    void onByteArrayRecievedFromAPI(byte[] inputStream)
}
}
```

And change you ASYC code to this

```
public class RetrievePDFStream extends AsyncTask<String, Void, byte[]> {

//public Fragment fContext;
//Change to This
public ApiResponseCallback callback;
PDFView pdfView;

public RetrievePDFStream( ApiResponseCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
protected byte[] doInBackground(String... strings) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(byte[] inputStream) {
    if(callback!=null){
        callback.onByteArrayRecievedFromAPI(inputStream);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In my fragment class there is an error that reads 'cyclic inheritance involved'. Also, it's implementing the ApiResponseCallback interface as MyFragment.ApiResponseCallback  in the fragment and as well as in RetrievePDFStream class. I need it to be independent of a specific fragment as I will be calling the RetrievePDFStream class from other fragments as well.

Comment: so please crate new java file for this call back so you can use as needed.